# Can we submit the specific html form using frameset and give the feeling of ajax in some sense?

Tags: java, html, frames

i am working on legacy project. In one of the jsp, it has cascaded frames  something like this

```
   <frameset >
     <frame src="Welcome.jsp">
        <frameset cols="9,*" >
     <frame src="Customer.jsp">
      <frame src="Account.jsp">
     </frameset>
  </frameset>
```

I have skipped the jsp code between frameset/frames.

Now inside one  account.jsp ,I am having the html form which gets submitted on click of submit button.The
  experience i see on UI is that only account.jsp is refreshed  with new data(leaving other jsps like welcome and customer intact). My understanding was this is
  possible only through ajax request. But when i drilled down  , i found it is same simple logic of form submission .

My question is then how come only that
  particluar frame is refreshed but not the complete page. Is it frameset feature? I tried to do the googling about it but  could not find relation of specific form
  submission with frameset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the frames to be different instances of browsers but presenting on same screen, (just like tabbed browsing) , we use frames only when we need all the parts to be detached and work as the way u said its working, if you want to update other frames from one frame use javascript to get hold of that frame and set the src property for that frame , if you want to revamp the whole page, then window.top.src = new_page

Comment: Does it mean if we do submit inside any frame only that frame will be submiited leaving others intact. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a form on an iframe, only that iframe will refresh.  That's just how it works.  I could not find documentation on it either.  It behaves like an entirely separate tab to a degree.  You can navigate in the frame as if it were a different tab, for example.  If you want to refresh the parent page, use this:
`parent.location.href = parent.location.href`

Comment: jeff. Its just a frame. I dont see anything related to iframe here.Does frame also work in similar way